# Add a field in table/view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate average values in a sql table/View by taking average of multiple values and want to group by another column.

For example in the attached excel sheet, I want to calculate average density from SG (Calc) field when Block ID is same.

[image]

```
+-----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+
| BlockID                           | SG (Calc) | Ave. Density |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+
| SESS_5835_01_OXD_SAP_AL01         |      1.86 |              |
| SESS_5835_01_OXD_SAP_AL01         |      1.71 |              |
| SESS_5835_01_OXD_SAP_MG04         |      2.08 |              |
| SESS_5835_01_OXD_SAP_MG04         |      2.14 |              |
| KCD_5897.5_01_OXD_TRA_VG02        |      2.74 |              |
| KCD_5897.5_01_OXD_TRA_VG02        |      2.74 |              |
| KCD_5897.5_01_OXD_TRA_VG02        |      2.51 |              |
| KCD_5895_01_OXD_TRA_MG06          |      3.19 |              |
| KCD_5895_01_OXD_TRA_MG06          |      3.02 |              |
| SESS_58932.5_01_OXD_TRA_MG05      |      2.24 |              |
| SESS_58932.5_01_OXD_TRA_MG05      |      2.27 |              |
+-----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: It will be great if you provide some table structure and sample data along with question.

Comment: Plain text (that can be copied and pasted) is preferred over screen shots here

Comment: Hi I want to calculate average of SG (Calc) in Ave.Density column when BlockId is same. Please advise How can I do it SQL table or do I need to create a view

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select a.*,avg(SG(Calc)) from table_name a group by a.BlockID;
```

Comment: Hi Nikhil, Thanks for your response. Can you please let me know how this can be calculated in Ave_Density column. We can have same ave values in all the rows where block id is same

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for window functions?

```
select a.*, avg(SG) over (partition by blockid) as avg_block_density
from t a ;
```